# Looping through R dataframe columns

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I want to loop a dataframe columns and use them for something else (in this case, performing a chi-squared test on all my features.

```
for(i in (1:ncol(wdbc))){
  wdbc[,i]
  chisq.test(wdbc$diagnosis,wdbc[,i])
}
```

I've tried referring to the features in all kinds of ways, for example:

```
chisq.test(wdbc$diagnosis,wdbc[i]) ##looping through colnames(wdbc)
```

or

```
chisq.test(wdbc$diagnosis,wdbc$i) ##looping through colnames(wdbc)
```

but can't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Try something like `lapply(wdbc, chisq.test)`

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

`wdbc[i]` will return a dataframe (rather than a vector), and `wdbc$i` doesn't work to loop through column names.

`wdbc[,i]` should work if `wdbc` is actually a dataframe. However, I've encountered an error in this type of situation before when my dataframe is not actually a dataframe but a tibble. The issue is that `wdbc[,i]` will still be a tibble rather than a vector. Try converting it to a dataframe with `as.data.frame(wdbc)`.